# textbox value set in javascript is not avaliable in serverside page load event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have following situation.I have set a textbox value by calling a JavaScript function from serverside.The textox value is assigned perfectly but it is not on server side it is showing blank.
This is my code.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "set", "setValue();", True)
        TextBox1.Text = txt.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

and This is my javascript function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function setValue() {
        document.getElementById("<%=txt.ClientID  %>").value = "Hello World";
    }

</script>
```

and here is my mark up

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClic" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The first texbox value is assigned perfectly.but it was not showin on second textbox.

Answer (score 1):

`txt.Text` value will not be accessible in the code, you can use below javascript code to achieve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setValue() {

        document.getElementById("<%=txt.ClientID%>").value = "Hello World";
        document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("<%=txt.ClientID%>").value;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: But I want to set this value from server side as it will be used in many places.The reason is that I want to get the screen width which is only possible in javascript and then use that value in server side.

Answer (score 1):

## I solve my problem with bellow method.

If you have TextBox that must be set in client side with JavaScript,

You must replace it with **HTML > Input(Text)**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

replace with:

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" runat="server" />
```

then in html source change it to **runat="server"**

now you can change its text in client side and get its value at server side with: **txt1.Value**

I Hope be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get value of textbox if you will assign it in your javascript function.

Try this way.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not IsPostBack Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Hi"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "set", "setValue();", True)
    TextBox1.Text = txt.Text
End If
End Sub
```

It may help you. Now Your Textbox value will be "Hello World". You have to assign some values before calling the javascript function.

**UPDATE**

The only solution is You must have to use Jquery Ajax to use textbox value in server side.

Use this link for your reference. [Jquery Ajax in ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17203/Using-jQuery-for-AJAX-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: True.It is not working. The only solution is you have to use jquery ajax to use textbox value in server side.